User looses project membership after some time
We are creating users and add them to projects within Autodesk ACC, programmatically via Autodesk Platform Services ACC API. Shortly after creation the user looses the membership in said project.
We are using the POST /users and POST projects/{projectId}/users endpoints of the APS ACC API.
Both request are accepted and confirmed by 201 HTTP-status code. Unfortunately after about 1-5 minutes the created users looses the membership in the project. Normally the membership should be permanent.

Does it happen to all users and all projects?  Or a specific user and a specific project?  Does adding user to account work?  The issue is when adding the user to a project?  Could you give us a example of failing call?  You can use this form https://aps.autodesk.com/contact-support .  client id, project id, and user id.  if you see x-request-id in the response header, please provide that as well.  Personally, I haven't heard such an issue.  But we can try asking the product team to take a look in the backend if there is anything not normal.
